# Howto deploy an Outlook addin only to our own staff

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app

We're developing an Outlook addin that is specific and proprietary to our organisation. So we'd rather not put it on AppSource and we'd rather not put the addin source files (all the js,css etc) on a publicly accessible url even if we can keep the manifest file private.

Is there a way, through centralised admin and deployment, to distribute this Outlook addin to our staff, using Group policies, and still keep all the addin files privately hosted somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you just host the files on an internal server?

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty but there are 2 issues with that.  If by internal server you mean a server within the office, then that would not work for all our office and remote workers round the world.  If by internal server you mean a web server with authentication so only our users can access it after logging in with username/password, I'm not sure that will work well from within the desktop outlook app as there is no browser as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which email server is hosting your mailboxes? Office365, on-prem Exchange Server or others?

Based on my research, if your mailbox is hosted by office365 , you could create a new message, then [**add a custom add-ins**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-on-the-web-8f2ce816-5df4-44a5-958c-f7f9d6dabdce) from your specific add-ins file(**New Message** > **...** > **Get Add-ins** > **My Add-ins** > **+ Add a custom add-ins** > **Add from file**):[image]

If your mailbox is hosted by on-prem Exchange server, you could grant enough **[permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins-2013-help)** for your staff, then add the custom add-ins via EAC, more details about how to install or remove add-ins: **[Install an add-in for Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/install-or-remove-outlook-add-ins-2013-help#install-an-add-in-for-outlook)**.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan_Wang.  We are on Office365.  I think I will just have to host the files somewhere, as specified by the doc link you included.  I was kind of hoping for a solution  where Microsoft hosted the files privately/transparently somewhere that's only accessible to our O365 users, but I'm realising that is wishful thinking.